# Checking empty dictionary condition and working with it in python

Tags: python

In my code I am having a default dictionary `mapp`. Now I want to check `if the dictionary is empty`, if so then I want to assign a value to the variable `final_class`, and if it is not empty then I want to assign a different value to `final_class`.

I am giving my code below:

```
mapp = defaultdict(list)
for i in match_gp[test_data] :
    mapp[i[-2]].append(float(i[-1]))
res = {k:sum(v) for k,v in mapp.items()}
res = dict(sorted(res.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))
if len(mapp) != 0:
    final_class = list(res)[0]
elif len(mapp) == 0:
    print("Empty")
    final_class = default_val
if (final_class == test_data[-1]):
    score_count += 1
```

Now I don't know why but the `empty` is getting printed whenever it is getting the empty dictionary but the score count is remaining the same, so it is more like it is doing the 1st if condition only, not the `elif`.

To give it another try I also tried like:

```
    mapp = defaultdict(list)
    for i in match_gp[test_data] :
        mapp[i[-2]].append(float(i[-1]))
    res = {k:sum(v) for k,v in mapp.items()}
    res = dict(sorted(res.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))
    if len(mapp) != 0:
        final_class = list(res)[0]
    elif len(mapp) == 0:
        print("Empty")
        final_class_1 = default_val
                
                
    if (final_class == test_data[-1]) or (final_class_1 == test_data[-1]):
        score_count += 1
```

But this above code is giving me the error saying : `NameError: name 'final_class_1' is not defined`

Please help me out.

Comment: "Now I don't know why but the empty is getting printed whenever it is getting the empty dictionary but the score count is remaining the same, so it is more like it is doing the 1st if condition only, not the elif." doesn't make sense to me. When `'empty'` is printed it did the `elif` condition. Besides `default_val` is used but never defined.

Comment: @jolvi default_val is a constant. I have pasted a small part of the code, it was defined. Can you say about the `NameError: name 'final_class_1' is not defined`